# Solr with JPA entities

Tags: solr

It would be great if someone provide your thoughts and hints on the below query on Apache Solr-JPA integration.

Entity #1: Employee [ id,firstname, lastname, List addresslist]
Entity #2: Address [addressid, city,state, country]

How to specify @Field annotation in entity for List addresslist variable in Employee entity?

How to define for addresslist and its attributes in schema.xml.